# Wpf TreeView's ScrollViewer Adjustment

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, scrollviewer, vertical-scroll

I am using a Wpf TreeView, in which I am adding nodes at runtime. Some times tree goes bigger and ScrollViewer comes into picture(that is part of TreeView's ControlTemplate). But everytime I add a node, I can not see it, cos it is outside the page area, I need to drag the vertical ScrollBar's thumb down in order to see it.
so I want the vertical ScrollBar to automatically drag to the point where the node is added so that I can see the node while adding it.

Any help please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use [BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview.aspx) to bring your new item into view, within any scrollable regions it is contained within. Pls, check an example below:

```
TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem() {  Header = "test" };
treeView1.Items.Add(item);
item.BringIntoView();
```

hope this helps, regards